# Received MethodError when cleaning String

Tags: julia, substring

I have data in a `.txt` file that looks like this:

```
04:31 Yuri Kane feat Jeza – Love Comes (Original Mix) [PREMIER]
25:31 Heatbeat & Quilla – Secret (Original Mix) [ARMADA CAPTIVATING]
```

All of them have this pattern:

```
00:00 artist - title [studio]
```

I want to remove the time stamp and the studio, so the output looks like this:

```
1. Yuri Kane feat Jeza – Love Comes (Original Mix)
```

Here is what I tried:

```
function remove_time_from(str::String)
  return last(split(str,"0 "))
end 

function remove_url(str::String)
  return first(rsplit(str,"["))
end

function main()
     
     tracks = String[]
     local number = 0
    
     for line in eachline("track-list.txt")
        number += 1
        removed_time = remove_time_from(line)
        cleaned = remove_url(removed_time)
        push!(tracks,"$number.$cleaned")
     end

     open("track-list-cleaned.txt", "w") do io
        for line in tracks
            write(io, "$line\n")
        end 
     end
end 

main()
```

but it returns:

```
MethodError: no method matching remove_url(::SubString{String})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the function `remove_time_from()` it uses `first()` which returns a `SubString{String}`:

```
track = "04:31 Yuri Kane feat Jeza – Love Comes (Original Mix) [PREMIER]"    
println(typeof(remove_time_from(track))) # Output: SubString{String}
```

You have 2 ways to fix it:

1. Have both `remove_time_from()` and `remove_url()` convert the `SubString` to `String` before returning it. This way, no matter which function you use first, you'll get a `String`:

```
return convert(String,last(split(str,"0 ")))
```

2. Use `AbstractString` instead of `String` as the function parameter, because `SubString` is a subtype of `AbstractString`:

```
println(SubString <: AbstractString) # Output: true
```

This way, no matter which function you use first, it would accept a `String` (the variable type of `line`) or `SubString` (the type you end up with after using one of the functions).

**Suggestions**:

1. Using `split(str,"0 ")` won't remove the time stamp:

```
last(split("04:31 Yuri Kane feat Jeza – Love Comes (Original Mix) [PREMIER]", "0 "))
Output: 04:31 Yuri Kane feat Jeza – Love Comes (Original Mix) [PREMIER]
```

What you need is [`chop()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.chop) and you can specify how many characters to ignore from the `head`, so in this case `5` (includes the leading whitespace).

```
chop(str, head = 5)
```

2. You don't need to read in the lines, clean it, and then store it in a `Vector` to write later. You can clean it (do it in one line), and write it out to the file:

```
open("track-list-cleaned.txt", "w") do io
    for line in eachline("track-list.txt")
        number += 1
        cleaned = (remove_url(remove_time_from(line)))
        write(io, "$number.$cleaned\n")
    end 
end
```

3. Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.enumerate) to number the lines as you're reading them in:

```
for (number,line) in enumerate(eachline("track-list.txt"))
```

**Code**:

```
# Using the assignment form because each function has only one line.
remove_time_from(str::AbstractString) = chop(str, head = 5)
remove_url(str::AbstractString) = first(rsplit(str," https"))

function main()
    open("track-list-cleaned.txt", "w") do io
        for (number,line) in enumerate(eachline("track-list.txt"))
            cleaned = strip(remove_url(remove_time_from(line)))
            write(io,"$number.$cleaned\n")
        end 
    end
end 

main()
```